# Checking if a Hamilton Cycle exists in a dense graph

Tags: c++, graph, hamiltonian-cycle

A few definitions first:

Definition 1

> A graph G = (V, E) is called ``dense'' if for each pair of non-adjacent vertices u and v, d(u) + d(v)>=n
>     where n = |V| and d(*) denotes the degree of the vertex *

Definition 2

> A ``Hamiltonian cycle'' on G is a sequence of vertices ( vi1, vi2,....vin, vi1 ) such that vil != vih for all l!=h and  { vil, vil} is an edge of G.

The problem is: write a program that, given a dense undirected graph G = (V; E) as input, determines whether G admits a Hamiltonian cycle on G and outputs that cycle, if there is one, or outputs ``N'' if there is none.

my solution is to find all the possible paths starting from a source and to check if a path exists that gets back to this source. Unfortunately, this solution is not efficient.

any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387725/what-is-dynamic-programming-algorithm-for-finding-a-hamiltonian-cycle?rq=1) uses dynamic programming to do the job.

Comment: Though the above post mentions it, I'll mention it as well to save some searching time - an algorithm exists, but it's not polynomial time. The decision version of Hamiltonian Cycle is NP-Hard. You're not going to find an "efficient" solution - well, if you do, then the computer science community would love to hear it. :)

Comment: According to Ore's theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore%27s_theorem), graphs satisfying Definition 1 always have a Hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: Wow...this is true @Tamás.....Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Ore's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore%27s_theorem), graphs satisfying Definition 1 always have a Hamiltonian cycle, and [Palmer's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore%27s_theorem#Algorithm) will give you one in O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Answer (score -2):

The problem is NP-hard. So I would not expect any solution to be much faster than brute-force.

Comment: Is it NP-hard even on dense graphs?

Comment: @avakar: No, it isn't; see my answer.

Comment: it's a trick....since the given graph is dense, it has Hamilton path!
but Tamas, you should also output that path which will not improve the solution!

Comment: oh sorry, when I answered the question, the definition of density was not included in the question, so I just gave an answer for the common case.